# How can I read a general html form fields send by POST method to my xPage?

Tags: xpages

I have a common HTML non-xpages form(part of non-xpages application) and I need to submit entered values to xpage and process it. How can I access these html form fields from xpage? In common I access html fields by its xpages componentId, but there is no such in this case.

Also from javascript I need to send JSON data to xpage using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, how can I access the submitted data? I tried to read some xPages API available here http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/index.html (specifically here http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/context/ExternalContextEx.html ) but it doesnt contain any comments and some mathods have very strange/common siganture like "java.lang.Object getRequest()" ... what is the request here( is it HttpServletRequest ???), where I can find some explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Values posted to XPages can be read using param.get(). I have written a blog post about a [HTTP request consumer in XPages](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2010/12/http-request-consumer-in-xpages.html) that you can use as inspiration.

Comment: To my big surprise it works like mentioned above. POSTed fields are accessible from param object. If you post field to URL with parameters with the same name as POSTed fields, the posted values have precendence.

Answer (score 0):

Although a solution was posted and accepted, (a long time ago) it should be noted that you don't have to use Xpages for this. Posting data to a 'normal' document record or using a basic LS agent and parsing out the posted 'content' would work just as well.